# Should we talk about consistency or congruence?

Tags: programming-languages, consistency

Always or absolutely most often very educated and professional partners I speak with talk about consistency (ie we shouldn't be able to prove something that is false)...Yet I suggested somewhat of a counterexample. Lying about everything seems to be "consistent" but not congruent. Therefore I suggested that we should speak of congruency when talking about language when consistency seems to be more about pure logic. Could we elaborate on this topic a bit since still much more emphasis is on consistency than congruence?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To what context(s) is your question meant to apply?

By strictly observing the way your question is tagged, I assume you meant to talk about programming languages in general. But I rarely see programming *languages* talked about in terms of consistency, and in fact, I struggle to understand how your example (this idea of a binary truth-falsity divide) is at all applicable to the design of programming languages.

In general, yes: logicians might talk about both consistency and congruence. But it's far more important that *subjective* standards like design patterns, coding standards, and even language architecture/design be *consistent*, since there is no universal or "correct" way of implementing them.

Beyond that, I'm not sure how congruence solves your counter-example of lying. Certainly there could be agreement on a lie, or any type of false premise. Even with the abstract definition of congruence as *similarity* between objects, I see little justification for a consistent lie's lack of symmetry.

Certainly we could have a lengthy discussion about the nature of Truth in general, and its specific relation to formal logic, but that would be clearly off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for the very good info. My brother is a Ph D in philosophy and published a paper on consistency of systems where I replied that always lying also is consistent(?) and programmers sometimes complain that an environment sometimes loosely said gave the programmer a sense of inconsistency maybe like premises are broken like a boolean variable should have only values true or false when in practice it also could have the value unset ie a third value.

Comment: @Niklas: I'll be honest, my academic studies in philosophy are mainly of a post-structuralist bent. I have a tendency to take issue with the idea of a universally defined and agreed-upon Truth. I'd enjoy the discussion if it were on topic. But it doesn't apply to programming regardless because things there are quite well defined. Boolean values aren't necessarily representative of larger, "worldly" concepts (they aren't intended to represent universal truths), but rather to capture the very mathematical binary computers operate in. 0s & 1s, True & False. There's no room for a third value.

Comment: I agree. Therefore the question they handled is badly stated: "Is this decision-making rational?" - that's asking for a boolean